# Aligning text baselines from 2 different divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align the baselines of 2 different div. the First div contains an H1 text while the other contains an H4. I have a border at the bottom for reference point.

```css
.row {
display: flex;
}

.col {
display: block;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h1>Title/Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h4>Subheader</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Illustration**

[image: Illustration]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, can you share the css code as well? this question only shows the html part of the code therefore we cannot help you to solve this problem, create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us that problems you are facing while attempting to do this, And also don't forget to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on how to ask a good question and what type of questions are [well suited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Comment: Thank you and Good Day, it doesn't have a CSS code yet, I tried using 'position: absolute, right:0, bottom:0' but seems to just position the text at the bottom of the screen itself and not the div area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flex properties for this.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 300px;
  background: yellow;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

h1, h4 {
  margin: 0;
}
h4 {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h1>Title/Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h4>Subheader</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it on my project and it fits the desired result well. Thank you very much. I didn't know about 'flex-direction property', I use flex when 'display: inline;' messes up my div format

Answer (score 0):

start with something like the code below. Margins and line height can change things. To make sure position absolute text does not go out of the parent box, you have to set that parent box to position relative

```css
.row {
display: flex;
}

.col {
display: block;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
height: 180px;
width: 180px;
background-color: yellow;
position: relative;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 20px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}
h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 10px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h1>Title/Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h4>Subheader</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```